# Craft 3: Environment variables are not parsed when used in Assets source field

Tags: assets, multi-environment, environmentvariables

I'm using Craft 3 and I have 2 Sites setup.

In my `config/general.php` file I have:

```
return [
    '*' => [
        'environmentVariables' => [
            'baseAssetsUrl' => '//'.strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']).'/assets/',
            'baseAssetsPath' => realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/../web/assets',
        ],
    ],

    'craft3uk.dev' => [
        'timezone' => 'Europe/London',
        'siteUrl' => 'http://www.craft3uk.dev/',
    ],

    'craft3me.dev' => [
        'timezone' => 'Asia/Dubai',
        'siteUrl' => 'http://www.craft3me.dev/',
    ],

    'dev' => [
        'devMode' => true,
    ],

    'staging' => [
    ],

    'production' => [
    ],
];
```

I can access the variables fine in a template like:

```
{% set baseAssetsUrl = craft.app.config.general.environmentVariables.baseAssetsUrl %}
{% set baseUploadsUrl = craft.app.config.general.environmentVariables.baseUploadsUrl %}
```

But when I try using `{baseAssetsPath}` like this

[image]

I get:

[image]

I'm a bit confused as I have a Craft 2 site setup the exact same way and this works fine.

I cannot see anything in the Craft 3 docs regarding this either?

Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environmental variables as such don't exist "as a thing" in Craft 3. Instead, you'd define your Volumes in the AdminCP and override anything you need in `craft/config/volumes.php`

You can see an example of how to do it here: [Craft 3 Multi-Environment](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft3-multi-environment)

Comment: Where in the Craft docs does it say to use `volumes.php` other than https://github.com/nystudio107/craft3-multi-environment ?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it - https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/master/en/configuration.md

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I guess I should read Craft 3 docs a few more times as I've obviously missed/forgotten some important changes.

Comment: The link https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/master/en/configuration.md appears to be dead.